# determine by a proof or a counterexample whether the following sets are sub vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Prove or disprove for every section if $U$ is a sub vector space.

1. $U = \{ B\in V |AB=0 \}$
2. $U = \{ B\in V |\det(AB)=0 \}$
3. $U = \{ B\in V |AB=BA \}$
4. $U = \{ B\in V |AB=B^t \}$

**My Attempt:**

1. $U = \{ B\in V |AB=0 \}$

What I'm most confused about is the matrix $B$. given $A_1, A_2 \in U$, then does this means that there exists $B_1, B_2 \in V$, such that not necessarily  $B_1 = B_2$ such that $A_1 B_1 =0$ and $A_2 B_2 =0$, so in order to prove that $U$ is closed under addition, we'll have to show that for every $A_1,A_2\in U: \exists B_3: (A_1 + A_2)B_3 =0$?

in this case, can we say that for $B_3=0: (A_1 + A_2)\cdot B_3 =  (A_1 + A_2)\cdot 0 = 0$.

this confusion continues on the other sections.

Comment: What do you know about $A$? Is it not a fixed element of $V$?

Comment: $A$ is most likely a fixed matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that $A$ is a fixed element of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$. In that case, the first $U$ is a vector space because:

1. if $AB_1=0$ and $AB_2=0$, then $A(B_1+B_2)=AB_1+AB_2=0$;
2. if $AB=0$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, then $A(\lambda B)=\lambda AB=0$.

The same approach should be used for the other sets.